# Automate Reading Lotto Numbers

Tags: spreadsheet, ocr

When we buy a large qty of Lotto tickets, is there a way to read all those numbers into a spreadsheet so that they can be checked against the winning numbers thru formulas/macros?

I am looking for an OCR application that can read the scanned PDF/JPG file and dump them into a file. (This might apply not only to Lotto, but also to other scanned documents.) As for checking for winning numbers, I know how to do it once I have them in a CSV/XLS file.

Comment: read them from what? paper tickets? website? email? text message? Sky box?

Comment: Only if you win.

Comment: About how many is "a large qty" ?

Comment: I am looking for an OCR application that can read the scanned PDF/JPG file and dump them into a file (This might apply not only to Lotto, but also to other scanned documents). As for checking for winning numbers, I know how to do it once I have them in a CSV/XLS file. Now you may decide if this is a REAL question or not.

Comment: @ neiling - Re-write your question with the text you put in that comment.

Comment: You might also want to calculate the probability of ... actually winning. o_< (WikiHow: Calculate Odds of Holding Winning Ticket http://www.wikihow.com/Figure-Your-Odds-of-Holding-a-Winning-Lottery-Ticket ) Don't mean to be offensive, but, the odds are not good.

Comment: Any plan that starts with "When we buy a large qty of Lotto tickets" is doomed to failure IMO. Have you even looked at the probability of winning? Better off to donate half of what you would have spent to charity and call it a day.

Answer (score 6):

You can scan them and use an OCR software to get the data from the tickets if they're clearly readable. Typereader 2008 by expervision is a great one that I've personally used before. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) offers alot of information on the subject.

As for the formulae, you could possible extract the average and median amount of times a number is represented in a given sequence and time frame and continue doing some calculations with that.

Comment: Beat me to the OCR suggestion +1

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a automated scanner, it would probably be quicker and less effort on your part to type the lotto numbers in by hand.

If you do this a lot and want to justify your effort:

1. Buy an automated scanner, with some sort of feeder.
2. Hopefully scanner will dump all the scanned files into a destination folder.
3. Run a script that will trigger OCR on each file in the folder.
4. Create a CSV file from the OCR dump
5. Import CSV into excel.

Several of these steps could be merged.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a spreadsheet for many years now that will automatically tally the winning tickets once the numbers are entered.  The tickets must all be entered by hand, though.

If you play the same numbers every time, you only need to enter them once.

Answer (score 0):

If you read them in to Excel from some format (OCR, type them in), you can just use the Excel search function to search for the winning number.